# Jersey 2.x post call throws SEVERE: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json

Tags: post, http-post, jersey-2.0

I tried to follow [tutorial jersey 2](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/REST/article.html), but I am falling into this exception that I cant shake off. The request has not reached the server as yet.

Exception

> http://localhost:8080/TBOAirAPIEndPoint/air/Consolidation
>   Jul 09, 2015 6:59:42 PM org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor aroundWriteTo
>
> SEVERE: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=class com.mcruiseon.airapi.tunnel.common.UserNamePassword, genericType=class com.mcruiseon.airapi.tunnel.common.UserNamePassword.

```
@Test
public void test1PostSearch() throws Exception {
    ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    URI url = UriBuilder.fromUri(
            "http://" + LOCALHOST + "/TBOAirAPIEndPoint/air/Consolidation")
            .build();
    WebTarget service = client.target(url);
    Response response = (Response) service
            .path("search")
            .path("/BOM/BLR/" + FlightSearchType.OneWay.ordinal()
                    + "/3/9/2015" + "/6/10/2015/"
                    + CabinClass.Economy.ordinal() + "/1/1/1")
            .request()
--exception--.post(Entity.entity(
                    new UserNamePassword("clientID", "password"),
                    MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON), Response.class);       
    assertNotNull(response);
}
```

Post Call

```
@POST
    @Path("search/{origin}/{destination}/{flightSearchType}/{departureDayOfMonth}/{departureMonthOfYear}/{departureYear}/{returnDayOfMonth}/{returnMonthOfYear}/{returnYear}/{cabinClass}/{adultCount}/{childCount}/{infantCount}")
    @Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    public Response search(@PathParam("origin") String origin,
            @PathParam("destination") String destination,
            @PathParam("flightSearchType") int flightSearchType,
            @PathParam("departureDayOfMonth") int departureDayOfMonth,
            @PathParam("departureMonthOfYear") int departureMonthOfYear,
            @PathParam("departureYear") int depatureYear,
            @PathParam("returnDayOfMonth") int returnDayOfMonth,
            @PathParam("returnMonthOfYear") int returnMonthOfYear,
            @PathParam("returnYear") int returnYear,
            @PathParam("cabinClass") int cabinClass,
            @PathParam("adultCount") int adultCount,
            @PathParam("childCount") int childCount,
            @PathParam("infantCount") int infantCount,
            JAXBElement<UserNamePassword> userNamePassword) {
```

Edit

```
    ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();
    config.property(MessageProperties.LEGACY_WORKERS_ORDERING, true);
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    URI url = UriBuilder.fromUri(
            "http://" + LOCALHOST + "/TBOAirAPIEndPoint/air/Consolidation")
            .build();
    WebTarget service = client.target(url);
    Response response = (Response) service
            .path("search")
            .path("/BOM/BLR/" + FlightSearchType.OneWay.ordinal()
                    + "/3/9/2015" + "/6/10/2015/"
                    + CabinClass.Economy.ordinal() + "/1/1/1")
            .request()
            .post(Entity.entity(
                    new UserNamePassword("clientID", "password"),
                    MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON), Response.class);
    assertNotNull(response);
```

Edit

I found [migration guide from 1.x to 2.x](http://20.1.3.%20MessageBodyReaders%20and%20MessageBodyWriters%20ordering). Frankly I dont care, I just this to work so I am happy to set `"jersey.config.workers.legacyOrdering") to true in ResourceConfig or ClientConfig properties.`. But where and how do I set this variable to true. Where is the ClientConfig

I also modified the junit code to

```
ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();
config.property("jersey.config.workers.legacyOrdering", true);
```

NOR did this work

```
ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();
config.property(MessageProperties.LEGACY_WORKERS_ORDERING, true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded Genson 1.3 for this to work. Version 0.94 does not work.

Comment: Yes, older versions of Genson work with jersey 1.x, recent ones work with both jersey 1 and 2.